# How can I use if else Model with value as null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was trying to use an `if else` statement with my model that contains `uname` as `username` but if its `null` then `Login/Register` will show up. Bet if its `!= null` the `ViewBag.username` will show.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    @if (Model.uname != null)
    {
        <a class="nav-link changing-color">@ViewBag.username</a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a class="nav-link changing-color" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight" id="login-register">Login / Register</a>
    }
</li>
```

I tried to do this but it always throw an error

> `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Is there anyway around to do this kind `if else`?

EDIT:

In addition these is only what I'm using on my `.cs`

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

When I put an `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]` it shows the same error above.

EDIT:

I also tried by using `<` operator as `boolean` but tag as redflag.

EDIT:

I also forgot to add my `HomeModel`:

```cs
public class HomeModel
{
    public string uname { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string user_type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In your get method, You don't pass any model to the view, So you need to check if the model is null first.

Comment: You mean I need to use `GetString` on my Controller first?

Comment: No, `sina_Islam`'s anwer is OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code a little. You check the user name null but not the model itself so you need to check that first.

```
 <li class="nav-item">
     @if (Model?.uname != null)
     {
         <a class="nav-link changing-color">@ViewBag.username</a>
     }
     else
     {
         <a class="nav-link changing-color" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight" id="login-register">Login / Register</a>
     }
 </li>
```

Also if you see your Index ActionMethod. You do not pass any model there. So the exception is at Model null not Model.uname.

Comment: I tried with `?` operator but it didn't show the `ViewBag` and it still exisiting the `Login/Register` since I look at `SearchBar` and it shows its `reg_no`

Comment: yes exactly. because it is not executing the block. so what you can do, is check the model null then use uname. It means the ViewBag value will show if the model itself is null or Model.uname is null. Becuase at your code ViewBag value will show if both conditions match.

Comment: Ah it means the code you given is only to check if the model is null?

Comment: As the error related to the null that is why I write that code. But if you see your code the ViewBag does not depend on uname of your model as you do not pass it. So you can pass the model from the ActionMethod or you can check both model and then property. Your code intension is, if the Model.uname !=null but the model itself is null. I prevent the null error. But the better approach will be
If(Model==null)
{
  <a class="nav-link changing-color">@ViewBag.username</a>
}
else if(Model?.uname != null)
{
    <a class="nav-link changing-color">@Model.uname</a>
}
then the else block.

Answer (score 0):

The first question in your code is you don't set any `ViewBag` in your controller, `ViewBag` is a dynamic object to pass data from controller to view, So you need to set it first.

The second question in your code is you just `return View()` in your controller, you don't pass any model to view, So when you want to make some judgments on the propertis of the model, the project will report `NullReferenceException`.

Refer to this demo:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
         HomeModel model = new HomeModel()
         {
             
            //Set the value of the property according to your situation
         }

         ViewBag.username= model.uname;
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View**

```
<li class="nav-item">
     @if (Model.uname != null)
     {
         <a class="nav-link changing-color">@ViewBag.username</a>
     }
     else
     {
         <a class="nav-link changing-color" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight" id="login-register">Login / Register</a>
     }
 </li>
```

In my opinion, If the model has the value,  you can just to use `@model.uname` instead of `@ViewBag.username`